# How can I use enum in a trait and implement trait on structs that are in the enum? Rust

Tags: rust, enums

I'm learning Rust so this might be a duplicate, since I'm still not sure how to search this. I tried to make a enum that contains different structs and since those structs have same methods but different implementation, I can't figure out how to properly write the types for the trait and the implementation. This is what I have so far:

```
struct Vector2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

struct Vector3 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

enum Vector {
    Vector2(Vector2),
    Vector3(Vector3),
}

trait VectorAdd {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector) -> Vector;
}

impl VectorAdd for Vector2 {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector2) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not compile, and the error messages don't make it clearer for me. Anyone can guide me how to write this properly? or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using generics here, you don't need the enum to write the trait:

```rust
struct Vector2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

struct Vector3 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

trait VectorAdd {
    fn add(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
}

impl VectorAdd for Vector2 {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector2) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

impl VectorAdd for Vector3 {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector3) -> Vector3 {
        Vector3 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a325d4a3acf4d947ccd2b8b34a2a69e0))

You can implement the `enum` based on this definition:

```rust
enum Vector {
    Vector2(Vector2),
    Vector3(Vector3),
}

impl VectorAdd for Vector {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector) -> Vector {
        match (self, other) {
            (Self::Vector2(a), Self::Vector2(b)) => Self::Vector2(a.add(b)),
            (Self::Vector3(a), Self::Vector3(b)) => Self::Vector3(a.add(b)),
            _ => panic!("invalid operands to Vector::add"),
        }
    }
}
```

Macros may help you if the number of variants gets large.

Comment: thanks, that answers the question, but I'm still wondering if I can do this with Enum? Because now VectorAdd can be implemented on any struct. Can I make it so the trait can be implemented only on certain structs?

Comment: @SnakesCantWearBoots based on what you're saying, what you might be looking for is what's known as ["sealed traits"](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#sealed-traits-protect-against-downstream-implementations-c-sealed)

Comment: @SnakesCantWearBoots I've updated the answer with information about the enum.  For trait privacy, see vallentin's comment.